# How to add color based on a condition in each item in a ListView in Android?

Tags: android, listview

When I try to display a color for each item in a ListView dynamiclly I'm getting wierd problem.
Problem was, I've 10 items in the list in which I supposed to apply background color to an item base on a paratemer passed to an adapter. Please find the code below

```
public class LazyAdapterForDelivery extends BaseAdapter {
   private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data = new ArrayList<>();
   private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;

   public LazyAdapterForDelivery(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String,    String>> d) {

       data=d;
       System.out.println("The Size of list in Lazy Adapter is: "+d.size());
       inflater = (LayoutInflater)a.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
   }
   public LazyAdapterForDelivery(Activity a) {
       inflater = (LayoutInflater)a.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
   }
   public void addItem(HashMap<String, String> item) {
       data.add(item);
       notifyDataSetChanged();
       System.err.println("the size of the adapter is in addItem: " + getCount());
   }
   public int getCount() {
       return data.size();
   }
   public void itemsAdded() {
       for(HashMap<String, String> map : data) {
           System.err.println("Items: "+map);
       }
   }

   public HashMap<String, String> getItem(int position) {
       return data.get(position);
   }

   public long getItemId(int position) {
       return position;
   }

   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       System.err.println("Inside GET VIEW");
       View vi=convertView;
       if(convertView==null)
           vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.aa_pod_lazy_adapter_delivery, null);

       TextView customerName = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.podDeliveryAdapterName); // Customer Name
       TextView trackingId = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.podDeliveryAdapterTrackingId); // Tracking Id
       TextView orderDetails = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.podDeliveryAdapterDetails); // duration
       RelativeLayout **colorLayout** = (RelativeLayout)vi.findViewById(R.id.colorLayout);   //backgroud color

       HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
       map = data.get(position);

       DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
       Date dbAssignedDate = new Date();
       String today =  dateFormat.format(dbAssignedDate);

       // Setting all values in listview
       customerName.setText(map.get(DeliveryListFragmentTab.CUSTOMER_NAME));
       trackingId.setText(map.get(DeliveryListFragmentTab.TRACKING_ID));
       orderDetails.setText(map.get(DeliveryListFragmentTab.ORDER_DETAILS));
       optionalMarking.setText(map.get(DeliveryListFragmentTab.OPTIONAL_MARKING));


       if(map.get(DeliveryListFragmentTab.COLOR_IDENTIFICATION)!= null && map.get(DeliveryListFragmentTab.COLOR_IDENTIFICATION).trim().length() > 0 && map.get(DeliveryListFragmentTab.COLOR_IDENTIFICATION).trim().equalsIgnoreCase("green")) {
          System.err.println("Inside green ifff");
          colorLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#6FA6FF"));
       } else if(map.get(DeliveryListFragmentTab.COLOR_IDENTIFICATION).trim().equalsIgnoreCase("yellow") ) {
           System.err.println("Inside yellow ifff and TrackingId = " + map.get(DeliveryListFragmentTab.TRACKING_ID));
           colorLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFB960"));
       }

       return vi;
   }
}
```

But, among 10 items, for only item I'm setting it's background color to yellow based on the adapter's parameter. Though, It's refelecting to some items in the list. When I scroll up and down for several times, all items in the ListView get's their backgroud yellow. Please help me if I'm wrong somewhere.
[Click Here](https://photos.google.com/album/AF1QipPWcLofNuyVP6iaCNpwk8bwWYXaYsh6bpj6FHtt/photo/AF1QipN8QlLRekystTJ0c5ePxHRNfxhm96y5DVC-Qn0Q) For an image of my list view where "VENKATESH GANGUMOLU" only supposed to have it's background color. But "Divya" also has it which it supposed to not have.

Comment: link to your image is down... :(

Comment: please don't try to highlight parts of your code like this: **colorLayout**. it makes the code invalid if someone for example wants to execute it.

Answer (score 0):

Its because there is no else condition in your code for color just add a else condition with some default color.

```
String defaultColor = "#ffffff"; // some default color or white color

if(map.get(DeliveryListFragmentTab.COLOR_IDENTIFICATION)!= null && map.get(DeliveryListFragmentTab.COLOR_IDENTIFICATION).trim().length() > 0 && map.get(DeliveryListFragmentTab.COLOR_IDENTIFICATION).trim().equalsIgnoreCase("green")) {
          System.err.println("Inside green ifff");
          colorLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#6FA6FF"));
       } else if(map.get(DeliveryListFragmentTab.COLOR_IDENTIFICATION).trim().equalsIgnoreCase("yellow") ) {
           System.err.println("Inside yellow ifff and TrackingId = " + map.get(DeliveryListFragmentTab.TRACKING_ID));
           colorLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFB960"));
       } else {
           colorLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(defaultColor));
       }
```

Comment: yes its depends on your code most probably it should be white, let me know if you have any issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `ViewHolder` pattern for implementing your `custom listview adapter`

first of all create `ViewHolder class` in your as follows

```
private static class ViewHolder {

   public TextView customerName;
   public TextView trackingId;
   public TextView orderDetails;
   public RelativeLayout colorLayout;
}
```

and then use it in `adapter's getView method` as follows

```
ViewHolder holder;
if (convertView == null) {
   convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.aa_pod_lazy_adapter_delivery, null);
   holder.customerName = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.podDeliveryAdapterName); // Customer Name
   holder.trackingId = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.podDeliveryAdapterTrackingId); // Tracking Id
   hodler.orderDetails = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.podDeliveryAdapterDetails); // duration
   holder.colorLayout= (RelativeLayout)vi.findViewById(R.id.colorLayout);   //backgroud color
   convertView.setTag(holder);
}
// view is recycling
else {
   holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
}
```

and use all references like

`customerName.setText` as `holder.customerName.setText`

Comment: not true! this is not a necessary. Only the RecyclerView forces you to use a ViewHolder.

Comment: @Downvoter it's always good practice to mention the reason for it in a comment.

Comment: maybe i didn't downvote.. but i gave you a reason why someone might downvote. your answer is not the solution... and using viewholder is not even necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this problem because you forgot to set default color in your file , so add one extra line in your code . try this one

```
 if(map.get(DeliveryListFragmentTab.COLOR_IDENTIFICATION)!= null && map.get(DeliveryListFragmentTab.COLOR_IDENTIFICATION).trim().length() > 0 && map.get(DeliveryListFragmentTab.COLOR_IDENTIFICATION).trim().equalsIgnoreCase("green")) {
      System.err.println("Inside green ifff");
      colorLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#6FA6FF"));
   } else if(map.get(DeliveryListFragmentTab.COLOR_IDENTIFICATION).trim().equalsIgnoreCase("yellow") ) {
       System.err.println("Inside yellow ifff and TrackingId = " + map.get(DeliveryListFragmentTab.TRACKING_ID));
       colorLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFB960"));
   }else{
      // ---------add this line -----------------
    colorLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF")); // white
}
```

Comment: you posted exactly Rahul's solution